# Rotate/transform print with Raphael and cufon weird results

Tags: javascript, animation, fonts, raphael, cufon

Cant find a fix for this anywhere! I want to produce a single character and then rotate it (inside a mouseover event). Since I need to use cufon for the custom font, print
must be used to summon the text. This works fine. But when in any way
trying to transform the single character weird things happen. It seems
to reset itself in size and placement, making it impossible to use.
Just applying a rotation with transform : "r0" makes the character huge and displaced in the middle of the screen.

Any thoughts on how to animate a printed "set" such as this??

```
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('elementDiv'), 1350,
900);
var custom = paper.print(5, 25, "A", paper.getFont("Web"),
30).attr({fill: "#000"});

custom[0].stop().animate({fill: "#4d3416", transform: "r20, s2"}, 300,
"<>");
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: please try this custom[0].stop().animate({fill: "#4d3416", transform: "...r20, s2"}, 300,
"<>")

Comment: This glitch seems to be addressed in the newest Raphael Library. Print also doesn't seem to produce sets no more. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been solved by newer Raphael libraries, animations on objects created by print is now behaving correctly